# How to access data of one function to another in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Okay the issue is something like this

I have a function in `AController`

```
public function index()
{
    $store = Store::(query)(to)(rows)->first();

    return view('store.index', compact('store'));
}
```

Now in the same controller I have another function

```
public function abc()
{
    return view('store.abc');
}
```

Now to this function I also want to send the `compact('store')` to the view `abc` I can just add the query again in the `abc()` function but that would be lazy and make performance issues. Is there a way that I can access `$store` object in other functions too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to access the same query from two places. So extract getting stores to another method like

```
private function store()
{
    $minutes = 10; // set here
    return Cache::remember('users', $minutes, function () {
        return Store::(query)(to)(rows)->first();
    });        
}
```

Additionally I have [cached](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/cache#cache-usage) the query. So it get executed once at a defiened time.

Then access it from other two methods like,

```
public function index()
{
    $store = $this->store();
    return view('store.index', compact('store'));
}

public function abc()
{
    $store = $this->store();
    return view('store.abc', compact('store'));
}
```

Comment: Each time I call `store()` it will run the query each time. That will be ineffective.

Comment: Let me update the answer for you. You can cache the query. It was available in Laravel 4.2. I need to check if it still available in laravel 5.1.

Comment: Okay I am waiting and I am using Laravel5.3

Comment: I updated my answer using cache and it support Laravel 5.3

Comment: @Alex was this helpful? If so appreciate your accept this answer and up-vote it.

Answer (score 1):

```
class StoreController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.store',['data' => $this->getSetting()]);
    }

    public function getStoreData()
    {
        //get your data here, for example
        $data = Store::where('status',1)->first();
        //get all data
        //$data = Store::all();
        return ($data);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Not testing but it should work for you.

```
class AController
{
    public function getStore()
    {
        $store = Store::(query)(to)(rows)->first();

        return compact('store');
    }

    public function index()
    { 
         return view('store.index', $this->getStore());
     }

     public function abc()
     {
         return view('store.abc', $this->getStore());
     }

}
```